# Woocommerce - campo especial dentro do jquery e usar opreadores de divisão

Tags: jquery, woocommerce

estou em um projeto pessoal, e estou com dificuldade em entender como funciona o jquery no woocommerce, eu utilizo o woocommerce como um sistema de cotação e estou tentado gerar uma tabela de preço dinamica de apresentação >>sem integração (eu nao vou salvar salvo os dados no BD )<< com o sistema do woocommerce, quero apenas uma tabela de apresentação na pagina do produto que utiliza os dados captados da loja como preço e alguns atributos.
O que eu tenho ate agora é o código abaixo:

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    var pc = 'p.price' //preco de custo
        q = $(pc).html();

    $('form.cart').on('show_variation', function( event, data ) {
        if ( data.price_html ) {
            $(pc).html(data.price_html); // mostra o valor
        }
    }).on('hide_variation', function( event ) {
        $(pc).html(q);
        
    });
});
</script>
```

Na pagina do produto do woocommerce eu tenho que captar o preço do produto (o código acima ja faz isso) e fazer uma formula com os campos atributo "pa_custo" e "pa_qdy"

a formula que eu gostaria de aplicar a este código seria

Preço do produto $(pc) + ("pa_custo" / (dividido) "pa_qdy") = x

alguém poderia me ajudar por favor?

Answer (score 0):

Se os seletores são classes seria neste exemplo:

```
  var ex = parseFloat($('.price').val()) + (parseFloat($('.pa_custo').val()) / parseFloat($('.pa_qdy').val());
```